# WebException when loading rss feed

Tags: c#, exception, rss, httpwebrequest

I am attempting to load a page I've received from an RSS feed and I receive the following WebException:

```
Cannot handle redirect from HTTP/HTTPS protocols to other dissimilar ones.
```

with an inner exception:

```
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

I wrote a code that would attempt loading the url via an `HttpWebRequest`.  Due to some suggestions I received, when the `HttpWebRequest` fails I then set the `AllowAutoRedirect` to `false` and basically manually loop through the iterations of redirect until I find out what ultimately fails.  Here's the code I'm using, please forgive the gratuitous `Console.Write/Writeline` calls:

```
Uri url = new Uri(val);
bool result = true;

System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
string source = String.Empty;
Uri responseURI;
try
{
    using (System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse())
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = webResponse as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            responseURI = httpWebResponse.ResponseUri;
            StreamReader reader;
            if (httpWebResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));
            }
            else if (httpWebResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(new DeflateStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));
            }
            else
            {
                reader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
            }
            source = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    req.Abort();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(source);
    result = true;
}
catch (ArgumentException ae)
{
    Console.WriteLine(url + "\n--\n" + ae.Message);
    result = false;
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    Console.WriteLine(url + "\n--\n" + we.Message);
    result = false;
        string urlValue = url.ToString();
    try
    {
        bool cont = true;
        int count = 0;
        do
        {
            req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(urlValue);
            req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
            req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            using (System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = webResponse as HttpWebResponse)
                {

                    responseURI = httpWebResponse.ResponseUri;
                    StreamReader reader;
                    if (httpWebResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
                    {
                        reader = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));
                    }
                    else if (httpWebResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
                    {
                        reader = new StreamReader(new DeflateStream(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
                    }
                    source = reader.ReadToEnd();

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
                    {
                        urlValue = httpWebResponse.Headers["Location"].ToString();
                        count++;
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cont = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (cont);
    }
    catch (UriFormatException uriEx)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(urlValue + "\n--\n" + uriEx.Message + "\r\n");
        result = false;
    }
    catch (WebException innerWE)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(urlValue + "\n--\n" + innerWE.Message+"\r\n");
        result = false;
    }
}

if (result)
    Console.WriteLine("testing successful");
else
    Console.WriteLine("testing unsuccessful");
```

Since this is currently just test code I hardcode `val` as `http://rss.nytimes.com/c/34625/f/642557/s/3d072012/sc/38/l/0Lartsbeat0Bblogs0Bnytimes0N0C20A140C0A70C30A0Csarah0Ekane0Eplay0Eamong0Eofferings0Eat0Est0Eanns0Ewarehouse0C0Dpartner0Frss0Gemc0Frss/story01.htm`

the ending url that gives the `UriFormatException` is:  `http:////www-nc.nytimes.com/2014/07/30/sarah-kane-play-among-offerings-at-st-anns-warehouse/?=_php=true&_type=blogs&_php=true&_type=blogs&_php=true&_type=blogs&_php=true&_type=blogs&_php=true&_type=blogs&_php=true&_type=blogs&_php=true&_type=blogs&partner=rss&emc=rss&_r=6&`

Now I'm sure if I'm missing something or if I'm doing the looping wrong, but if I take `val` and just put that into a browser the page loads fine, and if I take the url that causes the exception and put it in a browser I get taken to an account login for nytimes.

I have a number of these rss feed urls that are resulting in this problem.  I also have a large number of these rss feed urls that have no problem loading at all.  Let me know if there is any more information needed to help resolve this.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Could it be that I need to have some sort of cookie capability enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep track of the cookies while doing all your requests. You can use an instance of the [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) class to achieve that.

At the top of your method I made the following changes:

```
Uri url = new Uri(val);
bool result = true;

// keep all our cookies for the duration of our calls
var cookies = new CookieContainer();

System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

// assign our CookieContainer to the new request
req.CookieContainer = cookies;

string source = String.Empty;
Uri responseURI;
try
{
```

And in the exception handler where you create a new `HttpWebRequest`, you do the assignment from our `CookieContainer` again:

```
do
{
    req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(urlValue);

    // reuse our cookies!
    req.CookieContainer = cookies;

    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us,en;q=0.5");
    req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    using (System.Net.WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse())
    {
```

This makes sure that on each successive call the already present cookies are resend again in the next request. If you leave this out, no cookies are sent and therefore the site you try to visit assumes you are a fresh/new/unseen user and gives you a kind of authentication path.

If you want to store/keep cookies beyond this method you could move the cookie instance variable to a static public property so you can use all those cookies program-wide like so:

```
public static class Cookies
{
    static readonly CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();

    public static CookieContainer All
    {
        get
        {
            return _cookies;
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it in a `WebRequest`:

```
var req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
req.CookieContainer = Cookies.All;
```

Comment: before I loop back in the `do...while` would I not need to set the cookies to whatever value the `HttpWebRequest` might have contained?  basically in the `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))` block, add `cookies = req.CookieContainer;`??

Comment: Nope, that is all handled by the webrequest and the CookieContainer. No need to clean-up, that is all handled by the WebRequest and the CookieContainer.